# jQuery ajax field is return 'undefined'

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Project Created By Codeİgniter

Page and Response

Form Code

```html
<?php
$form_option = array('id' => $project->baslik ,'class' => 'form-horizontal');

echo form_open('ProjectStudent/add_project_student', $form_option); ?>
                                        
<input id="project_id" type="text" name="project_id" value="<?php echo $project->id; ?>" disabled="disabled"/>
<div align="right" class="col-md-12">
<select id="lesson_id" name="lesson_id">
 <option value="secim1_id">Seçim 1</option>
 <option value="secim2_id">Seçim 2</option>
 <option value="secim3_id">Seçim 3</option>
</select>
<button id="DersSec" type="button" class="btn btn-sm green">Ekle</button>
</div>
</form>
```

And jQuery Code

```html
$(document).ready(function() {

            $("button[type=button]").click(function(e){
                        var project_id = $(this).parent().find('input[name="project_id"]').val();
                        var lesson_id = $(this).parent().find('select[name="lesson_id"]').val();
                        var data = $(this).parent().serialize();
                        alert(data);
                        alert(project_id);
                        alert(lesson_id);
                    });
                  });
```

lesson_id is return a true data but project_id and data is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project_id field is out of the button's parent, so when you do

```
var project_id = $(this).parent().find('input[name="project_id"]').val();
```

you actually say: go to `<div align="right" class="col-md-12">` (the parent) and in it, look for an input field with the name `project_id`.

You just need to move the field inside the div, or access it with the upper parent like so:

```
var project_id = $(this).parents().eq(1).find('input[name="project_id"]').val();
```

Comment: Thanks for everythink

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the html structure of your document, you will see that the parent of the button is a `<div>` and not the `<form>`. That is why `project_id` and `data` are empty; `find()` finds nothing.

You could use something like:

```
$("button[type=button]").click(function(e){
    var form = $(this).closest('form'),
        project_id = form.find('input[name="project_id"]').val(),
        lesson_id = form.find('select[name="lesson_id"]').val(),
        data = form.serialize();
        ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Quickest amend to make (and get working) is to change `.parent()` to `.parents('form')`